# Delete for Spring won't work

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm not sure my syntax is correct.

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bakedGoods/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> deleteABakedGood(@PathVariable long id){
        bakedGoodsService.deleteABakedGoodInDB(id);
```

My Service

```
public void deleteABakedGoodInDB(long id) {
        bakedGoodsDAO.deletBakedGood(id);
```

My DAO

```
@Transactional
    public void deletBakedGood(long id) {
        em.remove(id);
        em.flush();
```

It says the long id isn't defined but the it is defined in the entity as id.

Comment: What says what? Post the exact and complete error message you get. Tell us when and how you get it. Also, a DELETE request is not supposed to return any response body.

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/finalproject-wheatt-api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Long] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Long

Comment: I get the error whenever I try to use Advanced rest client to delete a Item in the baked goods table. When the process is complete i want it to return a  Httpstatus ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So the exception is thrown by

```
em.remove(id);
```

And it says:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Long
```

And the javadoc of [`EntityManager.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) says:

> ```
> Remove the entity instance.
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>          entity - entity instance

So, remove() doesn't expect the ID of an entity. It expects an entity instance. BTW, with only an ID as argument, how could the entity manager know which type of entity it must delete?

You thus need something like

```
 BakedGood entity = em.getReference(BakedGood.class, id);
 em.remove(entity);
```

Comment: Hi JB, can you please answer to my post -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357979/when-to-use-request-session-application-scope-in-spring